# Edge sizing control is applying number of divisions and biasing unexpectedly

Tags: fluid-mechanics, ansys, ansys-workbench, fluent

When I generate Mesh elements in Ansys Fluent, they aren't generated as expected with the edge sizing control.

I've set the Edge Sizing control of this edge with these settings: (Number of Divisions: 20 and Biased):

[image]

With these settings it's expected to see on the edge: *20 mesh elements* and with their *size biased*.
But it's not the case: Their sizes are **not biased** and they are **not 20 mesh elements**.
[image]

---

These are the Mesh general settings:
[image]